# linq how to add symbol to empty lines from csv

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using this code to read csv files and make List out of them:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> appendLineNumbers(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    return lines
      .Select((line, index) => new {
         Line = line, 
         LineNumber = index
           .ToString()
           .Equals("0", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
              ? "RowNumber" 
              : (index + 1).ToString()})
      .Select(x => $"{x.LineNumber};{x.Line}");
}
```

As it is right now, when I read a file it will add a RowNumber even to a completed empty row. The result will be :

> RowNumer;

But I expect the line to have as many ";" as the Headline. Is it possible to put this into this statement or do I need to make an extra method for this.

Comment: Is a blank line allowed in a csv?

Comment: How about putting a `.Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))` after the `.Select`

Comment: Could you provide an *example* of the initial csv lines and the desired outcome, please?

Comment: @Neil the first select would have already enumerated the empty line and you would skip an index

Comment: @MongZhu That's not necessarily a problem because the index will reference the original data, which is probably why the index is being stored in the first place.

Comment: do you need to keep the empty lines at those positions ? simply skip the enumeration ?

Comment: the "where" pretty much did what I needed, i keep my rownumbers but dont have empty lines in my list.

Answer (score 0):

I would say right at the beginning remove the empty lines. The rest of your code should work then without this stumblestones of enumerating empty lines:

```
return lines.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
            . // here the rest of your code
```

If I missunderstood you please drop me a comment